# Calculation of Killing field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

In the picture below, I think $L_Vg=0$ equal to $g(\nabla_VX,Y)+g(X,\nabla_VY)=0$ . But if so , I can't get  equation of 2.7 . What's wrong ?

Picture below is from *SCALAR CURVATURE, KILLING VECTOR FIELDS
AND HARMONIC ONE-FORMS
ON COMPACT RIEMANNIAN MANIFOLDS*

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose $X,Y$ to be coordinate vector fields and you get $$g(\nabla_{\partial_i} V, \partial_j)=g(V^k{}_{,i}\partial_k,\partial_j)=V^k{}_{,i}g_{kj}=V_{j,i}.$$ Symmetrizing this gives you the correspondence you want.

Comment: I confuse $L_V(g(X,Y))$ and $(L_Vg)(X,Y)$,,